# Python - Convert a sparse matrix to JSON

Tags: python, json, data-structures, sparse-matrix

Looking for ways to convert a sparse matrix (from a text file) to JSON format (which would be a lot easier to parse into an HTML table) in Python. Not looking to reinvent the wheel unless I have to, so if there is a library out there that already does this, please let me know!

An example input would be (where the first number is always either 1 or 0 - for true or false, all values are separated by a space, and columns/indexes are indicated by the number before the colon):

```
1 1:2 3:1
1 2:3
```

To help you guys understand the input, below is the same input, just with zero-values and column headings included:

```
Flag    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
1       1:2    2:0    3:1    4:0    5:0
1       1:0    2:3    3:0    4:0    5:0
```

Preferred output (in JSON):

```
[
    {
            Flag: "1",
            Col1: "2",
            Col2: "0",
            Col3: "1",
            Col4: "0",
            Col5: "0",
        }
    {
            Flag: "1",
            COl1: "0",
            Col2: "3",
            Col3: "0",
            COl4: "0",
            Col5: "0",
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code can solve your problem:

```
import json

with open('matrix.txt') as f:
    content = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
    result = []
    for line in content:
        elems = line.split(' ')
        D = {x[0]:int(x[2]) for x in elems[1:]}
        row = {"Col"+str(i):D.get(str(i),0) for i in range(1,6)}
        row["Flag"] = int(elems[0])
        result.append(row)
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Considering that your matrix is in file `matrix.txt`, for each line you get the flag value and create a dictionary of pairs (column,value). Then it's easy to iterate over the range of possible columns and get the dictionary value (0 if not found) for the i-th column. Here I supposed that your matrix always has 5 columns, change the `range` otherwise.

Finally, you can use the `json` library to convert all the generated data. The `indent` parameter is used just to "prettify" the output and make it more readable for you, there is no need to use it in your final code.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Only complaint I have is that the columns are in descending order in the output (i.e. Col5 is first, and the Flag is last). Should be fairly easy to fix though...

Comment: The output I get is correctly ordered, but try adding a parameter `sort_keys=True` to `json.dumps`. Either way, keep in mind that JSON objects don't ensure any order. From the [official specification](http://www.json.org/): _an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs_.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

def convertMatrix(file_name):
    final_list = []
    try:
        with open(file_name, "r") as sparse_mat:
            matrix = sparse_mat.readlines()

        for row in matrix:
            each_dct = {}
            row_vals = row.rstrip("\n").split()

            if row_vals:
                each_dct["Flag"] = row_vals[0]
                for col_elem in row_vals[1:]:
                    if ":" in col_elem:
                        each_col_val = col_elem.split(":")
                        column_name = "Col"+each_col_val[0]
                        column_val = str(each_col_val[1])
                        each_dct[column_name] = column_val
                final_list.append(each_dct)
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception occured", e

    return final_list


print convertMatrix("demo.text")
```

By using this function you can get json. Just pass the text file name as you have said in you question.

Comment: While this does technically work; as it takes the text file and parses it into a JSON table, it doesn't generate the desired output (by generating zero-values when it doesn't find a value for that column number).

Comment: Can you give me your i/p and desired output. I have tried it is working good for me.